# How to authenticate with oauth 2.0 to Google Dataflow pipeline

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, dataflow

I am trying to use Google Dataflow pipeline python API using the following documentation: [Dataflow Python Docs](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/)
Upon first time trying to use the sample code with our project and it opened up the web asking for permissions. I granted all the permissions and then received "authentication completed" message in the web.

So I ran the python command again:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt \
                                     --output gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/counts \
                                     --runner DataflowRunner \
                                     --project your-gcp-project \
                                     --temp_location gs://<your-gcs-bucket>/tmp/
```

(This is the sample code, I entered our own project details)
and I always receive an 401 error

```
"error": {
```

"errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to testing_data_flow.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to testing_data_flow."
 }

I didn't find any working solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem.

I did not use the [google cloud sdk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads) and run [these commands](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/auth.html)